# Inaccurate output from awk converting very large numbers from hex to decimal

Tags: shell, awk

I have a following data: "210000000080401".
I need to convert the hex '210000000080401' to its decimal form.

Using Awk is not giving the correct result:

```
echo 210000000080401|awk -Wposix '{printf "%d %s\n", "0x" $1, $0}'
148618787703751680 210000000080401
```

while the correct value is 148618787703751681

```
echo 210000000080401 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'|xargs -i{} bash -c 'printf "%d\n" 0x{}'
148618787703751681
```

Why is Awk not giving the correct output?

Comment: Why post that lengthy shell line with a bunch of unnecessary commands and pipes instead of simply `printf "%d\n" 0x210000000080401`?

Comment: If you want precise handling of large integers, you'd be better off with Python, or `dc`, or `bc` -- either way, you want to pick a language with large integer support, which neither awk nor shell has.

Comment: f/e, correctly using dc for this purpose might look like `dc <<<'16i 210000000080401p'`

Comment: On a separate matter, `xargs -I{} bash -c '...{}...'` is an Extremely Bad Idea from a security perspective -- it means that anything xargs substitutes into `{}` is subject to being expanded _as code_ by the copy of bash that's started; if instead of a number you have a string that ends with `; rm -rf ~` (quoted so xargs doesn't split it), then you're getting exactly that command run by the shell as code.

Comment: What version of `awk` are you using?

Comment: @Daweo ..
version is: 
GNU Awk 4.0.2

Answer (score 5):

The POSIX awk spec doesn't define how to convert hex or octal strings to numbers, only decimal (e.g. when `"10foo"+0` becomes `10`), so don't add `-Wposix` to tell gawk to disable it's extensions and then do use the function `strtonum()` that the gawk folks provided for that purpose:

```
$ echo 210000000080401 | awk '{printf "%d %s\n", strtonum("0x" $1), $0}'
148618787703751680 210000000080401
```

otherwise you're asking for POSIX functionality but then relying on behavior that isn't defined by POSIX`*`.

The awk output being different by `1` from the shell output in the question, though, is due to such a large number being impacted by floating point arithmetic and/or precision available in awk - you'd have to google and/or read the gawk manual for a precise explanation of exactly what's happening in your specific case but if your gawk version is built to enable very large number handling  (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic) then you can do so by adding the `-M` argument and then you'll get the output you expected:

```
$ echo 210000000080401 | awk -M '{printf "%d %s\n", strtonum("0x" $1), $0}'
148618787703751681 210000000080401
```

`*` [The POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) has a section that says:

> Historical implementations of awk did not parse hexadecimal integer or
> floating constants like "0xa" and "0xap0". Due to an oversight, the
> 2001 through 2004 editions of this standard required support for
> hexadecimal floating constants. This was due to the reference to
> atof(). This version of the standard allows but does not require
> implementations to use atof() and includes a description of how
> floating-point numbers are recognized as an alternative to match
> historic behavior. The intent of this change is to allow
> implementations to recognize floating-point constants according to
> either the ISO/IEC 9899:1990 standard or ISO/IEC 9899:1999 standard,
> and to allow (but not require) implementations to recognize
> hexadecimal integer constants.

which means a POSIX awk may or may not consider hex constants such as `print 0x2f` as numbers but even that doesn't mean that converting strings that look like hex numbers to numbers, e.g. with `print ("0x2f" + 0)`, is defined by POSIX. So here's some fun behaviors allowed by POSIX (but demonstrated by GNU awk with/without `--posix` to show what different awks could do):

Defined by POSIX (so any awk must do this to be POSIX compliant)::

```
$ echo '0x2f' | awk --posix '{print $0}'
0x2f
$ echo '0x2f' | awk '{print $0}'
0x2f
```

Undefined by POSIX (so any awk can do either one or anything else they like and still be POSIX compliant):

```
$ echo '0x2f' | awk --posix '{print $0+0}'
47
$ echo '0x2f' | awk '{print $0+0}'
0

$ awk --posix 'BEGIN{print 0x2f}'
0
$ awk 'BEGIN{print 0x2f}'
47
```

and here is how GNU awk (without `--posix`) chooses to implement the desired functionality and is POSIX-compliant in doing so as only the first one is defined by POSIX:

```
$ echo '0x2f' | awk '{print $0}'
0x2f
$ echo '0x2f' | awk '{print $0+0}'
0
$ echo '0x2f' | awk '{print strtonum($0)}'
47
$ echo '0x2f' | awk '{print 0x2f}'
47
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 210000000080401 | gawk -nMbe '($2 = +("0x" $1))^_'
```

---

```
210000000080401 148618787703751681
```

If the input already has the `"0x"` or `"0X"` prefix, and you don't care about retaining the hex input, then it's much simpler :

```
echo 0x210000000080401 | gawk -nMbe '($_+=_)^_'
```

---

```
148618787703751681
```

Or say, if you wanna direct square a hex input :

```
echo 0x210000000080401 | gawk -nMbe '($_ ^= 2 )^_'
                      or 
                       | gawk -nMbe '($_ *= $_)^_'
```

---

```
22087544058532811854128322510325761
```